# How to migrate a Google Assistant Action to V3 of the SDK and platform?

Tags: actions-on-google

The [Google Actions SDK](https://github.com/actions-on-google/assistant-conversation-nodejs) has been rewritten again for version 3 and comes with a completely new developer platform with different ways of working. As far as I can tell, there is no way to migrate a legacy (Actions SDK V2) action to the new SDK and Actions Console experience.

Is there a documented way to migrate to V3?
Is anyone who has successfully migrated able to share their experience and any problems they ran into?

I haven't found any usable documentation on switching versions so my best guess is to start from scratch with a new project, then delete the old one and rename the new one. Is that likely to work?

My app is a simple conversational Action implemented with the `actions-on-google@v2.x` SDK. I did not use Dialogflow at all.

#### Progress so far

I've had some partial success by using the new version of the `gactions` CLI.

I created a new project using the new web console experience then pulled the configuration down from the server. I then pulled my existing project configuration down, edited the files to match the test project, then pushed it back up.

This has resulted in the web console UX changing to match the new experience but there is a residual error that prevents me from testing my app.

> Custom actions can only be specified in Conversational Actions projects.

This makes me think that there is some kind of **project type** in the back-end that determines what should happen in the web console. Pushing a modernised configuration up to the server seems to have changed the UI mode without changing the project type, causing an issue that prevents any maintenance on the old app or any migration to the new version of the system.

**Update**: A new migration workflow for Dialogflow Actions was just released. This is not relevant to my app because I never used Dialogflow.

Comment: Are you migrating from using Actions SDK v2 directly? Or were you using Dialogflow?

Comment: Migrating from Actions SDK v2.

Comment: A migration tool was launched by the team yesterday. This will help make it easier for you. The announcement is shared on Twitter https://twitter.com/ActionsOnGoogle/status/1303730732804780033?s=20. 

But here're the relevant documentation that will help.

[Overview] ->  https://goo.gle/3bHkAzz

[Project migration] -> https://goo.gle/3mggzqW

[Fulfillment migration] ->  https://goo.gle/2Rb1mZK

Comment: The Dialogflow migration documentation is not applicable to my app, which was written without Dialogflow, instead just using a simple web app for fullfilment.